# Why does moviepy complain about bitrate while generating audiofile?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, libx264, moviepy

I have just try to use `moviepy` library for the first time. Generation of movies from `numpy` arrays was really simple, intuitive and worked out of box. This is what I tried:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoClip
import numpy as np

def make_frame(t):

    val = int(255.0*(t/3.0))

    ls = []
    for height in range(100):
        row = []
        for width in range(300):
            row.append([val,0,0])
        ls.append(row)
    frame = np.array(ls)
    return frame

animation = VideoClip(make_frame, duration = 3)

animation.write_gif('first_try.gif', fps=24)
animation.write_videofile('first_try.mp4', fps=24)
```

Then I wanted to use `moviepy` to generate sound. In theory it should work in a very similar way. Here is what I tried:

```
from moviepy.editor import AudioClip
import numpy as np

make_frame = lambda t : 2*[ np.sin(404 * 2 * np.pi * t) ]
clip = AudioClip(make_frame, duration=5)

clip.write_audiofile('sound.mp4')
```

However, I got an error message:

```
[MoviePy] Writing audio in sound.mp4
|----------| 0/111   0% [elapsed: 00:00 left: ?, ? iters/sec]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sound.py", line 9, in <module>
    clip.write_audiofile('sound.mp4')
  File "<string>", line 2, in write_audiofile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 204, in write_audiofile
    verbose=verbose, ffmpeg_params=ffmpeg_params)
  File "<string>", line 2, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 162, in ffmpeg_audiowrite
    writer.write_frames(chunk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 122, in write_frames
    raise IOError(error)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file sound.mp4:

Invalid encoder type 'libx264'


The audio export failed, possily because the bitrate you specified was two high or too low for the video codec.
```

Does anybody know what this error means and how this problem can be resolved?

Comment: *"Invalid encoder type 'libx264'"* error seems unrelated to "bitrate". Do you have that codec installed? have you tried `.mp3` extension (to create an audio-file) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write a soundfile with a mp4 extension. Instead, use ".mp3", ".wav", ".ogg", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Zulko's solution is correct, but I the answer to the actual question, 'Why does moviepy complain about the bitrate?' is that the line `The audio/video export failed, possily because the bitrate you specified was two high or too low for the video codec.` is a generic line printed after most failed export attempts. It is rarely the actual solution.

If you think it might be, call `clip.write_videofile("output.mp4", bitrate=500)` and set bitrate to whatever you want.